# Accelerating expansion or local underdensity of universe?

Tags: cosmology

How do measurments of the Hubble constant distinguish between accelerating expansion of the universe and a local cosmic matter underdensity?

I understand that the directly measured value of Ho is much greater (about 1.3 times) than the value inferred by precise measurements of the CMB.   I understand that one explanation for this difference is the suggestion that we live in a region of the universe in which there is an underdensity of matter.  Measurements of the amount of matter in the local supercluster suggest that region we occupy has somewhere between a tenth and a quarter of the amount of matter there is on average the universe.  This could account for the higher measured value of Ho.   But when scientists concluded the expansion of the universe is accelerating did they not also use the same measured (higher) value of Ho, rather than the Plank data which was only released recently.  Does the Plank data bring into question the idea that the expansion is accelerating?